# Python Holoviews responsive chart with sizing_mode property

Tags: python, charts, responsive, bokeh, holoviews

I'm using Holoviews and Bokeh and have an issue.
Using Bokeh I can specify the sizing_mode="scale_width" property, so my charts will be responsive.
And it works fine now.
But I couldn't find anything like this for Hovowiews.

```
boxwhisker = hv.BoxWhisker(df, ['cyl', 'origin'], 'mpg', label='')
boxwhisker.options(show_legend=False, height=200, sizing_mode='scale_width')
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
boxChart = renderer.get_plot(boxwhisker).state
boxChart.name = 'boxChart'

curdoc().add_root(boxChart)
```

sizing_mode='scale_width' is second line is not working, so I have my chart size fixed, not responsive.

Is the any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot do that directly via Holoviews, but there is a way through extracting a Bokeh plot from a Holoviews one. The idea is taken from [this Holoviews page](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html) under 'Combining HoloViews and Bokeh Plots/Widgets'.

The above example could be made responsive as follows:

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout

hv.extension('bokeh')

data = [[1, 'A', 5],
        [1, 'A', 3],
        [1, 'B', 10],
        [1, 'B', 5],
        [2, 'A', 5],
        [2, 'A', 19],
        [2, 'B', 7],
        [2, 'B', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['cyl', 'origin', 'mpg'])

boxwhisker = hv.BoxWhisker(df, ['cyl', 'origin'], 'mpg', label='')
boxwhisker.options(show_legend=False, height=200)
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')
doc = curdoc()
box_chart = renderer.get_plot(boxwhisker, doc)
doc.name = 'boxChart'
plot_layout = layout(box_chart.state, sizing_mode='scale_width')
doc.add_root(plot_layout)
```